# Iteration in vuejs2

Tags: loops, vuejs2, iteration

I fetched data from database and trying to display in a table using vuejs2 like below. Here I would like to have a `continue` (programming continue) for a specific value in `obj`. I would not like to create a `td` if `key == id`.

```
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="obj in gdata">
                <td v-for="(value, key) in obj">
                    <template>                            
                        {{value}}
                    </template>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer below as helpful, as it appears to be complete, and not issues were raised regarding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to show some items, you can implement like this:

```
   <tbody>
        <tr v-for="obj in gdata">
            <td v-for="(value, key) in obj" v-if="value !== someValue">
                <template>                            
                    {{value}}
                </template>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```